# Using bash to edit text file and display output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a text file with courses that looks like this:

```
csc 4567 - Computer Programming
This course is about stuff...blah blah blah
4.0000 credit hours
```

I need to write a bash script that takes the text file and extracts the necessary information to display course number, course name, course credit hours. No spaces, just commas between. Course credit hours as whole number.

I can extract the information using command line but I am lost when writing the bash script. I am guessing I should be using the grep and sed with bash?  I'm not sure.  This is what I have (which is obviously not anywhere near correct). Any advice would be appreciated.

```sh
while read courses.txt
do
  $courseLine=grep -iE '^csc [0-9]{4}'
  $creditHours=grep -iE '^[0-4]'
  $courseNumber=${courseLine#/s/s*}
  $courseName=${courseLine%/s/s*}
  printf "$courseNumber,$courseName,$creditHours"
done
```

Above what I am trying to accomplish is: read the file line
save "csc 4567 - Comp prog" as course line
save "4" as credit hours
save everything left of second space in course line as course number
save everything right of second space in course line as course name
then display my desired output.

It should print csc4567,Computer Programming,4

And yes, this is homework, but since I am new to the forum it won't let me tag the post as such.

Comment: So in the case of that example (csc 4567) what should it print?

Comment: You're lacking some basic understanding of bash syntax. Like you have to use `var=$(command)` or `var=\`command\`` to put the output of a command into a variable, not `var=command`. BTW, even old users can't use the homework tag, it's deprecated.

Comment: Can you use a tool like `sed`, or must it be pure bash?

Comment: Yes I have to use bash.

Comment: I changed my script to this:    `while read line;do
  courseLine='$line|grep -iE ^csc [0-9]{4}' 
  creditHours='$line|grep -iE '^[0-4]''
  courseNumber=${courseLine#/s*}
  courseName=${courseLine%/s*}
  echo $courseNumber,$courseName,$courseHours
  done <courses.txt`  
I'm not sure if this is progress or not...?

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/bash
while read line
do
 if [[ $line =~ ^(csc\ [0-9]+)\ \-(.*)+ ]]; then
      a="$a${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
elif [[ $line =~ ^([0-9]+)([0-9\.\,])+\ credit ]]; then
    a="$a,${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\n"
#else
  # a="$a,$line" 
fi

done < "a1.txt"
echo -e $a
```